# UPDATE SET WITH JOIN Error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-update

I am getting an output of `0 rows affected` Can someone tell me why this update statement will not work?

```
UPDATE 
  LEAGUE
SET
    [ALL_STAR] = '1'
  , [PLAYER] = 'ACTIVE'
  , [DATE] = GETDATE()
FROM 
    ASSOCIATION an 
    LEFT JOIN LEAGUE lg ON lg.[PLAYER_ID] = an.[PLAYER_ID] 
WHERE 
    lg.[ALL_STAR] IS NULL
    AND lg.[PLAYER] IS NULL
    AND lg.[DATE] IS NULL
```

Comment: Please press the link to see image

Comment: Why can't you write that code in the question instead?

Comment: If you are doing a left join it means that the LEAGUE table might not have a record. so you can't update you would need an insert instead

Comment: Uh...does that even run without a syntax error? There is a space missing in the `andlg.PLAYER is null` statement. It should be `and lg.PLAYER is null`.

Comment: I am sorry about that. Yes I have put a space in between and and lg.PLAYER and still get 0 rows affected. I don't understand why the update doesn't take effect.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: 1) Please write the code as text in the question   2) Give details about the tables and the date they contain (as small set of sample data the reproduces the issue).   Maybe there is no data that matches your query.

Comment: I Don't understand the rude responses...I just want help on my code.

Comment: Nobody is being rude, they are just telling you how to write a good question as per the rules and guidelines of this site.

Comment: This is not a "help with my code" site, but rather a question and answer repository, where *repository* is the key word. So your question and its answer should be helpful for all future visitors, and not just you, which is why we're trying to get you to improve your question. Rather than complain about perceived rudenss, why not help us and all future visitors out, and follow our recommendations? Again, please post your code as code-formatted text, and not as an image. This way future visitors can copy and paste your code into their IDE's and test it themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a select statement to see what records will be affected.

I think a "NOT IN" statement is what you're after. When you test, you should be using transactions so you can do the rollback without changing any records.

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE 
  LEAGUE
SET
    ALL_STAR = '1'
  , PLAYER = 'ACTIVE'
  , [DATE] = GETDATE()
FROM 
    LEAGUE lg
WHERE 
    lg.PLAYER_ID NOT IN (SELECT an.PLAYER_ID FROM ASSOCIATION an)

PRINT '******* ROLLBACK TRANSACTION ******* ';
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

--PRINT '******* COMMIT TRANSACTION ******* ';
--COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Ok so when I did this I got 1118 Records. But when I do the update I get "0 rows effected." Why is this?

Comment: Hi Tony, thank you for your answer. The reason it was not working was because I was attempting to update NULL values. I had not included the proper values for the Player ID unique identifier. I will keep that in mind next time. The good news is that I just figured it out! Thank you so much